# Sqlite3 on Python 2.5 is too slow

Tags: python, sqlite

When I access an Sqlite database using Python 2.5, it takes too long, but if I access the same database by other ways (including Python 3.2) it takes much shorter. What's going on? (I need Python 2.5 and can't switch to Python 3.2)

Comment: Can it be even python 2.6 or 2.7?

Comment: Do you have indexes on fields used in JOINs and in WHERE clauses?

Comment: I tried Python 2.7 and it works. Still I'd like to know other solution. If I share my code I need to tell to switch to 2.7. Python 2.5 comes with a software many use at my company.

Comment: I don't have any index, I'll see if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should go without saying that if you use an old version of a program, you don't get the performance improvements, bug fixes, and feature additions that were added later. Python 2.5 is slower, buggier, and less powerful than 2.7 (or 3.2) in many ways, and for the most part, the only solution is "Stop using 2.5", unless you want to track down the specific improvement in the changelogs and backport it to the 2.5 codebase.

But in this case, it's a lot easier, because `sqlite3` is developed independently of Python (in fact, before 2.5, it didn't even come built in), as [`pysqlite`](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/). Here's some version history (as seen in the What's New documentation for [2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html) and [2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html)):

- Python 2.5: pysqlite 2.3.2
- Python 2.6: pysqlite 2.4.1
- Python 2.7: pysqlite 2.6.0

The latest version is 2.6.3. You can install it by using any of the usual means (`pip`, `easy_install`, downloading it from the website and following the instructions, downloading the Windows binary installers from the website and running them, etc.).

In fact, if you're building a package with `setuptools`/`distribute`, you may just be able to put in a requirement for `>= 2.6.0`, and `pip install mypackage` will automatically get the new version for 2.5 (and 2.6 users).

It's also possible that your problem is with the underlying C `sqlite3` library, not the `pysqlite` wrapper. If you install `sqlite3` and then build `pysqlite` from source, you can solve that too.

If you're not sure which version you have, you can check at runtime, because the module has a human-readable `version` attribute (and a `version_info` tuple just like the one in `sys`, so you can check `version_info >= (2, 6)`), and likewise `sqlite_version` and `sqlite_version_info` for the underlying C library.

Comment: Your answer comes with a lot of information and suggestions that will help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to abarnert's excellent answer, look at how often you are committing.  Comitting is slow in SQLite and generally performance benefits if it is put off.  I encountered this myself during some [other testing](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance/90243/) I did and the performance difference of reducing the number of commits is enormous.

Comment: That's very good advice in general, but if that were his problem, why would Python 2.7/3.2 (pysqlite 2.6.0) solve it? Auto-committing each insert is still ridiculously slow in the latest versions. (For the record, I agree that he should probably look into this—anyone who cares about sqlite performance and doesn't know this needs to learn it.)

Comment: I don't know why the version would matter that much.  Of course, he says he needs 2.5 so it's possible that the code he is running under 2.5 and what he is testing in 3.x is actually different in an important way, like committing more often in his 2.5 code.

Comment: That's possible—but remember, he also tested in 2.7, and it solved the problem too. And I'd think his 2.7 code would be more like his 2.5 code than like his 3.2 code—in fact, it likely just _is_ his 2.5 code. It's more likely that one of the dozens of performance-related packages to pysqlite between 2.3.2 (2 Jul 2006) and 2.6.0 (5 Mar 2010) are the issue.

Comment: I tested the same code in 2.5, 2.7 and 3.2. I need Python 2 because I need a package that only works on Python 2 (that I didn't use on the tests)

Comment: @José That makes sense.  I don't know what caused it then.  I still do a lot in 2.7 due to some packages that haven't migrated yet, but I haven't had problems with performance, as long as I use the commits intelligently.